# Audio Playback in Firefox malfunctioning at around 98%

Tags: javascript, firefox, html5-audio

I'm working with user-uploaded audio in javascript/html5, such that the user file input becomes the src for an audio element. In all my development so far, things have been working very well in chrome and safari; but I have one problem with firefox that I can't figure out and I don't know where to begin looking.  Other than this, firefox works fine, too!

Consistently I'm finding that when audio.currentTime is very near to audio.duration (about 98%, to be more precise), the play and pause methods don't work properly.  When I try to pause the audio at any point past ~98%, the audio just finishes playing. Trying to play the audio then defaults to doing whatever happens when one plays the audio after it has ended.

If audio controls are on, the slider works as it should stopping and starting no matter when play or pause are called.

This is really bugging me out... anyone have any ideas, similar experiences?

Comment: Should have included:  all browsers versions are up to date on my computer.